# Full Text Search not returning correct results

Tags: sql, t-sql, full-text-search, sql-server-2014, stop-words

We have a full text index on an xml field in our database.

If I run this query:

```
select *
  from UserProfile
  where CONTAINS(UserData,'028894507')
```

I get the correct results.  But if I run this query:

```
select *
  from UserProfile
  where CONTAINS(UserData,'02889')
```

I get a completely different set of results and it doesn't even include the results from the first query.

I did a quick google search and found that there are stop words that can throw off results, but there isn't even a stop list in my database...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a TSQL expert, however - 
I believe CONTAINS searches for whole word matches. You can also search for prefix matches using the `*` character.

`select * from UserProfile where CONTAINS(UserData,'"02889*"')`

This should match rows containing `028894507`, as well as any row with a number starting with `02889`. Note the double quotes are important when doing a prefix match.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx